# Highlight Parent Nav Element

Tags: css, wordpress, nav, elementor

I want the parent nav menu (Test1) to be highlighted when the sub menu item (Test 2) is activated:  [image: 1]

With the following code I was able to modify the pointer but only if I hover over with the mouse.

```
.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main .current-menu-parent:not(.e--pointer-framed)  
.elementor-item:after  
{background-color: yellow !important;}
```

What do I have to change to keep the yellow underline even if I move the mouse away from nav menu?

Regards

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML in your question, we're happy to help you solve your problems but we're not able to accurately guess your document structure. Please see the "*[mcve]*" and "*[ask]*" guidance, and also take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
body[data-elementor-device-mode=desktop] header.sticky-header .elementor-widget-nav- 
menu .elementor-nav-menu--main .current-menu-parent:not(.e--pointer-framed) 

.elementor-item.has-submenu:not(:hover):not(:focus):not(.elementor-item- 
active):not(.highlighted)::before,


.elementor-widget-nav-menu .elementor-nav-menu--main .current-menu-parent:not(.e-- 
pointer-framed) 


.elementor-item.has-submenu:not(:hover):not(:focus):not(.elementor-item- 
active):not(.highlighted)::after 
{ 
opacity: 1;
}
```